# Incorrect Timezone in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script that is pulling a time from a given row on a spreadsheet and then transcribing it. However, the timezone is getting completely messed up in the process.

Relevant code (functional bits snipped out because I don't think they're relevant):

```js
var timezone = "GMT+" + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;
function dysfunction(row) {
  this.time = new Date (sheet.getRange(row,6).getValue());
  this.time.setFullYear(2020);
  this.timeString = Utilities.formatDate(this.time, timezone, "hh:mm a");
  Logger.log(timezone);
  Logger.log(this.time);
  Logger.log(this.timeString);
}
```

Stackdriver Log on executions:

```
May 4, 2020, 9:43:52 PM Info    GMT+6
May 4, 2020, 9:43:52 PM Info    Wed Dec 30 14:00:00 GMT-07:00 2020
May 4, 2020, 9:43:52 PM Info    03:00 AM
```

My correct timezone is in fact GMT-07:00, but for some reason, the script is detecting my timezone as GMT+6. I have set the correct timezone in the Project properties and even declared the timeZone as "America/Edmonton" in the manifest.

Where do I go next to figure out why this thing isn't interested in reading the timezone correctly?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, when you modified `Utilities.formatDate(this.time, timezone, "hh:mm a")` to `Utilities.formatDate(this.time, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm a")` and/or `Utilities.formatDate(this.time, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mm a")`, what values will you retrieve? [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone), [Ref2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone())

Comment: Make sure both the spreadsheet and the script have the exact same timezone. Otherwise, you might get wrong results, as you can see in [this Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153110455). Also, use the methods proposed by @Tanaike to retrieve the timezone.

Comment: @Tanaike you got it. Changed timezone variable to SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(). Now it works perfectly. I can't mark your comment as the solution, though - feel free to add and I'll check it off. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modification.

#### From:

```
Utilities.formatDate(this.time, timezone, "hh:mm a")
```

#### To:

```
Utilities.formatDate(this.time, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm a")
```

#### References:

- [getSpreadsheetTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone)

Comment: Thank you! It works, but with light modifications - `var d = new Date(); var date = Utilities.formatDate(d, sheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm a")`, sheet as var of already received sheet obj

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the timezone shift can vary, according to the season: +0700 or +0600 are correct shifts at 2 different seazons for the same timezone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, but +6/+7 are never correct for my timezone. I'm -7/-6. Which is why I knew I had a problem when the original code returned +6: if it was a DST issue, it would have returned -6.